# I had downloaded selenium webdriver.just writen first program but still getting same error

Tags: compiler-errors

package jshsj;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class J2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    


}
```

}
Opening in existing browser session.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-D6LV0OBJ', ip: '192.168.218.13', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at jshsj.J2.main(J2.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:36617/status] to be available after 20015 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
... 10 more

Answer (score 0):

We have to set up ChromeDriver path in webdriver.chrome.driver, not the chrome exe installed in our System. You can download the required exe file from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ based on the version of Chrome Browser in your system